# Password checking program, for loop problems

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, passwords

I'm working on a python program to check a series of passwords in a document to see if they are Valid. They must be 7 characters long, contain at least 1 Uppercase letter, 1 lowercase, letter, 1 number, and no other characters. For some reason my for loop terminates after checking only the first character and I can't figure out what the problem is. Can someone take a look at my code and help me figure this out?

```
def detectLength(word):
    if len(word) >= 7:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def detectSpecial(word):        
    if word.isalnum:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def detectCapital(word):
    for i in range(0, len(word)+1):
        if (ord(word[i]) >= 65 and ord(word[i]) <= 90):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def detectLower(word):
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if (ord(word[i]) >= 97 and ord(word[i]) <= 122):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def detectDigit(word):
    for i in word:
        if ord(i) >= 40 and ord(i) <= 57:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def main():
    print(format("Password Attempt", '20s'), format("Validity Result", '17s'), format("Reason", '15s'))
    print("======================================================")
    word = input()
    while word != "ZZZZ":
        if detectLength(word) == False:
            Validity, Reason = "Invalid", "Length"
        elif detectSpecial(word) == False:
            Validity, Reason = "Invalid", "Special Char"        
        elif detectCapital(word) == False:
            Validity, Reason = "Invalid", "No Uppercase"
        elif detectLower(word) == False:
            Validity, Reason = "Invalid", "No Lowercase"
        elif detectDigit(word) == False:
            Validity, Reason = "Invalid", "No Digits"
        else:
            Validity, Reason = "Valid", ""
        print(format(word, '20s'), format(Validity, '20s'), format(Reason, '14s'))
        word = input()
    print("======================================================")

main()
```

Comment: Pro tip: comparison tests already return `True` or `False`; just return the comparison outcome. You also need to *call* `word.isalnum()`. And instead of `if something == False:`, use `if not something:`.

Comment: Yeah, word.isalnum() needed to be called, but now it's saying password attempts with capital letters outside the first letter are not alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of how you structure your for-loops. In `detectCapital`you return `False` if the first char is not uppercase. You should return `True` if it is uppercase and if the loop is finished and no `True` was returned, then clearly all letters are lowercase and a `False` should be returned. Like so:

```
def detectCapital(word):
    for i in range(0, len(word)+1):
        if (ord(word[i]) >= 65 and ord(word[i]) <= 90):
            return True
    return False
```

You also have the same problem in `detectLower` and `detectDigit`.